# Need coding help: Drag and drop back to revert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i remove the droppable item from drop list, it should be add to the dragable list.

can you please help me with the coding how i can make it visiable in the drag list again.

HTML:

```
<div class="draggable"> <div class="cs-drop">drag 1 
    <a href="#"> remove</a></div></div>
<div class="draggable">drag 2</div>
<div class="draggable">drag 3</div>

<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<div class="droppable">drop here</div>
<div class="droppable">drop here</div>
<div class="droppable">drop here</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
    .draggable { padding: 40px 25px; border: 1px solid red;  float: left;}
    .droppable { width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid black; float: left; }
    .droppable.active { background-color: red; }
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$('.draggable').draggable({ revert: true });
drop();
function drop()
{
$('.droppable').droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        $(this).html($(this).html()+ui.draggable.remove().html());
        $(this).droppable('destroy'); 
    }


});
}


         $(".droppable").on("click", "a", function (){       
         $(this).closest('.cs-drop').fadeOut(200, function() {$(this).remove();});  
             drop();
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code. YOu would need to optimize a little! Read the Draggable API more and go through some examples.

```
<div class="drag-item">
    <div class="cs-drop">drag 1 <a href="#"> remove</a></div>
    <div class="cs-drop">drag 2</div>
    <div class="cs-drop">drag 3</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div class="drop-container">drop here</div>
<div class="drop-container">drop here</div>
<div class="drop-container">drop here</div>

$('.cs-drop').draggable({
    revert: true
});
drop();

function drop() {
    $('.drop-container').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'active',
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
            $(this).droppable('destroy');
        }
    });
}

$(".drop-container").on("click", ".cs-drop a", function () {
    $(this).closest('.cs-drop').fadeOut(200, function () {
        $('.drag-item').prepend($(this).clone().css('display','block'));
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

the updated [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NXDhE/97/)

**and never user classess such as draggable/droppable since they are used by the jQuery framework aswell. Try something more unique.**

Comment: Yes working fine. But after remove the drag1, it is added to the drag list. again same drag1 need to drop. it is possible

Comment: yeas it is possible! you will need to implement the code in a different way!